# In the Github Android project, how is LoginActivity launched?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

The source code to the project is at https://github.com/github/android

I can't figure out how the LoginActivity is launched. The HomeActivity is the first activity launched. Somehow, the LoginActivity is launched as well. In general, it'd be great to have a strategy to track what Intent is launching an activity (where is that Intent object created). In this specific scenario, I just want to learn how authentication is implemented by the Github developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 1 part RTFM and 1 part being surprised at how the debugger works.

Github uses an AccountManager. You can start at the documentation at: http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html#ExtendThatThing

```
    <service
        android:name=".accounts.AccountAuthenticatorService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":auth" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>
```

Part 2 - By default break points set within the AccountAuthenticator will not fire because they are not running in the same `thread` com.github.mobile. Instead, it runs as "com.github.mobile:auth". You'll need to go into the DDMS perspective to martk com.github.mobile:auth as debuggable to use break points.